# JWT Authentication with Spring boot as seperate jar is not redirecting to Rest controller in other spring boot APP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have implemented Jwt token Authentication in spring boot app which is working fine.it will redirect to the specific rest api . When i have made the Rest API as seperate jar and trying to use JWt authentication jar in other Spring boot application, it is not redirecting to the Rest api urls in the restcontroller after authentication.Here is the code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

   @Autowired
   private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

   @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
   private String authenticationPath;

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
       // user for matching credentials
       // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
       auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       // We don't need CSRF for this example

       httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
               // dont authenticate this particular request
               .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
               // all other requests need to be authenticated
                       anyRequest().authenticated().and().
               // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
               // store user's state.
                       exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

       // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request

       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


   }


}
```

```
   JwtRequestFilter.java


@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtRequestFilter.class);


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);


            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
      //  LOGGER.debug("UserEmailId extracted from token"+ username);

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException | CertificateException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }


        //Once we get the token validate it.
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);




            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set authentication
            try {
                if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken,userDetails)) {

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                    // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);


                //  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);


                }
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("redirecturl"+request.getRequestURI());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class Empcontroller {



    @GetMapping(value= "/welcome")
    public ResponseEntity<String> welcome()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Welcome User!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: after authentication from the jar  , it will not redirect to the restcontroller API url  in the spring boot application. Need anyone help to resolve the issue

Comment: I am not sure i understand, using jwt token means you dont have to redirect because if the token is valid it should go directly  to the page, shouldn't it?

Comment: when i make a request  with http://localhost:8083/welcome  it validates the token by calling  spring boot application(which is a seperate jar) but it does n't redirect to the EmpController which is present in other Spring boot Application.

Comment: should i missed any configuration to redirect to the API url ?

Comment: Any help is appreciated